# Label captions don't fit within their coordinates on some resolutions/zoom levels for out VB6 application

Tags: vb6, screen-resolution, label

Our VB6 application uses Twips throughout. On some systems that have aberrant resolutions like 1360*768 or which have a zoom level of the desktop of 125% or higher the captions of the labels don't fit within the box specified by the Width and Height properties.This produces very ugly results. Can someone explain what is at stake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resolve these issues you might start by reading [User Interface - High DPI Awareness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the linked resources provided there.  You'll find a suggested process for diagnosing and correcting several of the issues your programs might be running into.

There hasn't been a lot on the topic written specifically for VB6 development.  This means you'll have to do some concept translation.

Comment: This (and localisation to Japanese) is why all my labels are now autosize/wordwrap with the controls reflowed to suit.